# Fastest efficient way to create XML document .NET/Oracle and return to web client

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oracle

Does anyone know which is the fastest most efficient way to create XML documents in an Oracle/.NET environment.

There are two philosophies:

1. Do the coding in an Oracle Package and Use Oracles native XML abilities to return an XML document after querying the data from the DB, create the document by then looping through your Query result setting nodes like so (addXMLNode(doc, nContact, 'ROW_ID', rec_con.ROW_ID);)
2. Just query the Data from Oracle and use .NET on the data looping through the data reader and create your XML document using .NET XML classes.  Essentially letting the DB serve the data, and DOM XML creation is done in .NET.

Assuming no knowledge difference in the two practices, does someone know if one is more efficient, faster, or better than the other one?  Please don't give me your "favorite" way to handle it.  An "our query was slow so we moved it into the code", or vice versa real world example would give me some direction for code refactoring and application performance improvement.

Thanks.

Comment: I think something to consider is which "layer" you think will last longer in terms of use. If your database is going to be Oracle-based for a long time, then sticking the XML generation there might be a good idea so you can swap out .NET for something else without a hassle. And the other way around, if .NET is sticking around, put the XML generation there so the database backend doesn't matter.

Comment: Well neither are going anywhere for this particular application, but I understand what you are saying.  From an internal knowledge and support standpoint Oracle is the way to go, which is how it is done now. It is slow...., and I was just wondering if someone had made this move before and seen improvements or if it degraded and Oracle was the fastest.  Keep in mind it is Oracle 9.2 so the XML abilities might be lacking.  I am just not familiar enough with Oracle to know if that is the best way.  I am sure removing some of the Select * in the package will speed it up too.